# maven shade plugin override a file

Tags: java, maven, maven-shade-plugin

I am using maven shade plugin to create a fat jar. I want to override 1 properties file that is coming from a jar i don't control. I want to update that properties file before creating the shaded jar. I tried using transformers configuration but when i am trying to override I am getting error

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-shade-plugin:3.2.4:shade (default) on project dsp-santa-breakbox: Error creating shaded jar: duplicate entry: assets/components/hystrixCommand/hystrixCommand.js -> [Help 1]
```

Here is my shade plugin configuration

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.4</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <transformers>
                                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.IncludeResourceTransformer">
                                    <resource>assets/components/hystrixCommand/hystrixCommand.js</resource>
                                    <file>src/main/resources/hystrixCommand.js</file>
                                </transformer>
                            </transformers>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i had to filter the file from other artifact,
Here is how the final configuration looked like

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.4</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <filters>
                                <filter>
                                    <artifact>com.yammer.breakerbox:breakerbox-service</artifact>
                                    <excludes>
                                        <exclude>assets/components/hystrixCommand/hystrixCommand.js</exclude>
                                    </excludes>
                                </filter>
                            </filters>
                            <transformers>
                                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.IncludeResourceTransformer">
                                    <resource>assets/components/hystrixCommand/hystrixCommand.js</resource>
                                    <file>src/main/resources/hystrixCommand.js</file>
                                </transformer>
                            </transformers>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```